# RuntimeException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

i am retrieving records from a table called PurchaseDetailContributor by using another table joins.but i am getting query error.

below is my DAOHibernate.java class inside i worte a method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<PurchaseDetailContributor> getPurchaseDetailContributorByCustomerNo(Integer customer_no) {
    System.out.println("The Customer number in PurchaseDetailContributorDAOHIbernate >>>>" + customer_no);
    String sql = " SELECT * FROM purchase_detail_contributor pdc "
             + " INNER JOIN purchasedetail pd ON pdc.purchase_detail_id = pd.purchasedetailid "
             + " INNER JOIN purchase p ON pd.purchasefk = p.purchaseid " 
             + " INNER JOIN user u ON u.userid = p.userid AND u.customer_no = " +customer_no;

    List<PurchaseDetailContributor> pdcList = new ArrayList<PurchaseDetailContributor>();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(PurchaseDetailContributor.class);
        //sqlQuery.setInteger("customer_no", customer_no);
        pdcList = sqlQuery.list();
        tx.commit();
    }catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("getPurchaseDetailContributorByCustomerNo() >>>>- RuntimeException: " + e);
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            try {
                // Second try catch as the rollback could fail as well
                tx.rollback();
            } catch (HibernateException e1) {
                System.out.println("Error rolling back transaction: " + e1);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        session.disconnect();
    }
```

my error is in join query.

//error information

```
1:13:00,713 DEBUG [UserDAOHibernate:774] findUsersByCustomer_no() - Namequery: GetUsersByCustomer_no, 57835
11:13:00,752 DEBUG [UserDAOHibernate:774] findUsersByCustomer_no() - Namequery: GetUsersByCustomer_no, 57835
This COMPANYID is before passing from  FORM >>>>>>>>41
This COMPANYtype after passing id from FORM >>>>>>>>UnTrusted
The customer number is >>>>>>57835
User select values is Untrusted
Inside try condition
The Customer number in PurchaseDetailContributorDAOHIbernate *********57835
11:13:01,073 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter:233] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
11:13:01,074 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter:234] Column 'is_approved' not found.
getPurchaseDetailContributorByCustomerNo() ====222>>>>- RuntimeException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.newscom.action.AccountAdminAction.updateTheCustomer(AccountAdminAction.java:4749)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
```

Comment: You need some spaces when you add the "inner join" and "where"  clauses,  otherwise your sql will be something like "select * from  purchase_detail_contributorinner join...".

Comment: @Insac & @ stanislavL ,thanks now i changed the sql query as you people suggested but still i am getting the following error     org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: can you print your SQL before submitting it and adding it to the question?

Comment: i didn't get what your telling...can you please modify the errors in my code.

Comment: To help us understand what might go wrong,  can you add some information? For example the complete stacktrace and/or the value of the sql variable?

Comment: @insac, i have added the error details..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125692/discussion-between-fakkir-mohamed-sait-and-insac).

Comment: You should provide the full stack trace. I'm pretty sure the SQL error is better explained there.

Comment: Pleaso add also a diagram of the model, maybe it's just a typo in a column's name.

Comment: @LluisMartinez : thanks,now it is working fine...i missed one column...

Answer (score 1):

You have no spaces in your sql

```
String sql = "select * from purchase_detail_contributor"
         + "inner join purchasedetail on (purchase_detail_contributor.purchase_detail_id = purchasedetail.purchasedetailid)"
         + "inner join purchase on (purchasedetail.purchasefk = purchase.purchaseid)" 
         + "inner join user on (user.userid = purchase.userid)"
         + "where user.customer_no = :customer_no";
```

So the sql is

```
select * from purchase_detail_contributorinner join purchasedetail...
```

Which is definitely syntax error

Comment: You have to always set the parameters like `user.customer_no = :cno` when creating the query, then call `setParameter("cno", customer_no)` to protect against SQL injection attacks. This one is safer, because it's an Integer object, but if you're doing it like this in one place, it's safe to assume you're doing it in a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Did you post correct code?

As in error it shows

```
11:13:01,074 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter:234] Column 'is_approved' not found.
```